# how to use jquery-ui with nodejs?

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, jquery-ui

i am trying to use jquery-ui draggable() function in a nodejs, with the help of JSdom, i was able to get jquery working with jsdom but the jquery-ui is not working.
not knowing how to link both library or make it work

```
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path'); 

const htmlPage = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname,'../views/search.ejs'));
const { window } = new JSDOM(htmlPage);
const $ = require('jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui')(window);

exports.getSearch = (req, res) => {
    res.render('search', {pageTitle: 'Search'});
    $('.item').draggable();
    // console.log($('.main-head'));
}
```

after executing npm start, there is a error

```
/home/jquery/node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js:14
            factory( jQuery );
                     ^

ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at /home/jquery/node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js:14:12
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jquery/node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js:16:2)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/Nodejs/jquery/controller/search-controller.js:9:11)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

search.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-head">
        <div class="item">
            <h1>item1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h1>item2</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to figure this out this week myself. I was not able to get jquery-ui to be initialized on a JSDOM window in any way that seemed to work (I tried including it via both inline and cdn scripts as well as an npm module). I've concluded that it might be best to simply mock the jquery-ui methods that are relevant for a test.

In my `setupTests.ts` file, I have the following code which solves the error that you shared by making jQuery accessible in line 14 of `jquery-ui.js`:

```
(global as any).$ = require('jquery');
(global as any).jQuery = (global as any).$;  // first setup global.jQuery...
require('jquery-ui');                        // then initialize jquery-ui
```

I am using jest, so this is set as my setupFile in `jest.config.js`. You should just need to execute these lines before your use of jquery-ui.

```
module.exports = {

    ...

    "setupFiles": [
        "<rootDir>/tests/setupTests.ts"
    ],
```

However, while loading jquery-ui in this way does get us past the particular error you shared, I did not find it to work as intended with JSDOM. jquery-ui methods are still `undefined` when I try to call them on elements in the JSDOM.

So, I am mocking the necessary methods for my tests like so. :)

```
const dom = new JSDOM('<html> ... </html>');

const $ = require('jquery')(dom.window.document);

const tooltip = jest.fn(() => {});
$.__proto__.tooltip = tooltip;              // mocks a jquery-ui method

testThatUsesJQuery($);                      // executes the code under test

expect(tooltip).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(4);   // expects the method to have been called
```